# Remove Duplicate Group of Data in Text file

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a text file formatted similar to the following:

```
Description1:        Data-123<br>
Description2:        Data-ABC<br>
Description3:        Data-789<br>
Description4:        Data-EFG<br>
Description5:        Data-XYZ<br>

Description1:        Data-123<br>
Description2:        Data-ABC<br>
Description3:        Data-789<br>
Description4:        Data-EFG<br>
Description5:        Data-XYZ<br>

Description1:        Data-123<br>
Description2:        Data-ABC<br>
Description3:        Data-789<br>
Description4:        Data-EFG<br>
Description5:        Data-584<br>
```

I need PowerShell to compare each group (5 lines of data) as a whole and remove any duplicate groups, leaving only the unique groups of data. I can get it to remove single duplicate lines with the code below, but no luck comparing each group.

```
get-content TextFile.txt | sort-object | get-unique > NewTextFile.txt
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: If you want help, show what you've done already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work, you need to create the output file based on the result of last line of code, anyway I give no explanation because you don't show us any code you have so far.

```
$a = gc mylist.txt

$b = [string]::Empty
$c = @()

$a | % {if ( $_ -ne [string]::Empty ) 
            { $b += "$_`n"  } 
        else 
            { $c += $b
              $b = [string]::Empty 
            }   
}    
$c += $b    
$c | select -Unique | out-file .\mynew.txt
```

Comment: Whoops sorry for not posting, I've added it. Thanks!

Comment: @user2441508 Berofe the unique you need to group the five lines in a single entity, try my code. If last line isn't the last line of the last group of five but an empty one for example, you need to manage it in a different way.

Comment: This seems to be working, I just made sure the last line is not blank. The only issue I ran into was while trying to use out-file to write to a txt file. When I do this, it only outputs the unique lines, not the whole groups.

Comment: You are right, my mistake.  The output it just formatted slightly different to the text file, but it's all there. Way too many things going on today :). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Split the file content on double new line characters (that should match the end of the line right before the empty line + the empty line right after it), split each object returned (remove the empty line) and then join it back, add new line and write the results to a new file.

```
(Get-Content TextFile.txt | Out-String) -split "`r`n`r`n" | ForEach-Object{
    ($_.Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join "`r`n") + "`n"
} | Select-Object -Unique | Out-File NewTextFile.txt
```

Comment: You need to handle the last group in a different way if there isn't the last empty line. Try your code editing the textfile.txt making equals the last two groups.

Comment: I tried with or without an empty line after the last group and got the same result.

Comment: with the example provided in the OP is true, try changing it making the last two group equals and the first different..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you confirm this plz?  (Get-Content file.txt | Out-String) -split "`r`n" | foreach{ $_.Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions ]::RemoveEmptyEntries)} | Select-Object -Unique

Comment: um.. this doesn't group by five and then it returns the unique sigle lines value.

Comment: And this? (Get-Content D:\temp\g.txt | Out-String) -split "`r`n`r`n" | ForEach-Object{
    $_.Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions ]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join "`r`n"
} | Select-Object -Unique | Foreach {$_ + "`n"}

Comment: @C.B. thanks for your help, much appreciated! I will update my answer with it.

Comment: Always with pleasure @ShayLevy

Comment: While running this I'm getting the error: "Unable to find type [System.StringSplitOptions ]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: Try to remove the space right before the closing bracket, not sure if that's the cause. I also removed it from the code, copy it and try again.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the help! I also checked both results from your code and C.B. and the results are both the same, so I know for sure I am good. Thanks again to the both of you!